# Training with Tensorflow without a fixed batch size

Tags: tensorflow, artificial-intelligence

Basically I am using video's as data to train my model. The amount of frames per video is not fixed thus the `X` in `model.fit` doesn't work as it doesn't have a shape which can be made a numpy array.

How can I fit my data with this bad shape?

Should I make a loop and fit batch per batch?

I made a loop calling `model.fit` on every batch separately
I also tried doing `np.array(sequence, dtype=object)`, but this resulted in:

`ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type numpy.ndarray).`